# android - how to create dynamic group of buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, margin

I have list of names for buttons in runtime. How can I create buttons?

```
    int marginTop = 0;

    for(String s : locations){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(s);
        //setContentView(button);

        //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //MarginLayoutParams src = new MarginLayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(src);
        //params.setMargins(0, marginTop, 0, 0);
        //this.addContentView(button, params);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, marginTop, 0, 0);

        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addContentView(button, params);
        marginTop += 50;
    }
```

I tried this, but nothing works, buttons are hide in a row, not below.

And after this I want to dynamically react to buttons click event and starting diffrent activities.

Comment: Can you show the image, how the layout should look after all the buttons are set ?

Comment: yes, you see 
http://prntscr.com/1oyil8
One is hidden behind another :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for(String s : locations){
 Button button = new Button(this);
 button.setText(s);
 button.setId(ID);
 LinearLayout mylayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.location_layout); mylayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.La‌​youtParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.setMargins(0, marginTop, 0, 0);
 button.setLayoutParams(params);
 mylayout.addView(button);
 marginTop += 5;
 ID++; 
}
```

here is a sample code that you can use: [useful link](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/add-a-textview-and-a-button-to-linear-layout-programmatically/)

Comment: Well, this guide me to the right way :-) thanks.
I meant this [screen](http://prntscr.com/1oyxgu)

`for(String s : locations){
 Button button = new Button(this);
 button.setText(s);
 button.setId(ID);
 LinearLayout mylayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
 mylayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.setMargins(0, marginTop, 0, 0);
 button.setLayoutParams(params);
 mylayout.addView(button);
 marginTop += 5;
 ID++;
}`

Comment: I will change the answer and put this code on it. Glad it helped ;)